# Git-TF - Why use configure

Tags: tfs, git-tf

On my linux machine I setup Git-TF (https://gittf.codeplex.com/). I am curious with the instructions, why do I need to use configure? it says that is when you are working on a multiple man team, but if I do not do this can I not just do git tf pull?

So can I just clone my tfs repo and do my work, or should I really follow the second example and do a configure first? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The git tf configure command is used to configure an **existing** git repo to be able to communicate with a TFS server, then developer can share changes in existing Git repo to TFS.

If you're not in this scenario, you just need to run git tf clone command to initializes a new git repo from an existing path in a TFS server.